# Laravel event won't work

Tags: php, mysql, events, laravel, event-listener

I have setup an event that does some stuff once a user registers. Updating and inserting etc, but it won't work.

I get the error:

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class 'EventHandlers\Handlers\User' not found**

I don't know why it won't work. But I haven't misspelled anything, because if I eg "return 'test';" in my event it works, but it won't update my userModel

In my Usercontroller:

```
$user = User::create([

    some values..

]);


Event::fire('user.create', $user);
```

Now I subscribe to events in my app/start/global.php, I autoload the folder using PSR-4

```
Event::subscribe('EventHandlers\Handlers\UserAccountActions');
Event::subscribe('EventHandlers\Handlers\ProductActions');
Event::subscribe('EventHandlers\Handlers\CommentActions');
```

And in my event/listener file

```
<?php namespace EventHandlers\Handlers;

class UserAccountActions {

    // Listeners
    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen('user.create', 'EventHandlers\Handlers\UserAccountActions@onCreate');
    }

    // happens when a user register
    public function onCreate($user)
    {
        $user->api_key = User::createApiKey();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `EventHandlers\Handlers\UserAccountActions` you refer to `User` as it was in the same namespace. You need to add a backslash `\` to access the `User` class in the global namespace:

```
// happens when a user register
public function onCreate($user)
{
    $user->api_key = \User::createApiKey();
}
```

(Or specify the namespace if the `User` model is in one. e.g. `\Models\User`)

Alternatively you can also import the model with a use statement:

```
use User;

class UserAccountActions {
```